# how to pass up-down arrow values to bash terminal Process called from Java

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell, sh

I have a Java Process that interacts with a bash terminal:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("bash", "-i");
Process process = pb.start();
```

At some moments I need to simulate the type of an arrow (up, down):

```
String arrowUpKey = "??????????"
String arrowDownKey = "??????????"

OutputStream in = process.getOutputStream();
in.write(arrowUpKey.getBytes());
in.flush();
...
in.write(arrowDownKey.getBytes());
in.flush();
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

bash doesn't work as a GUI. It works with input and output datas from files named stdin / stdout.

If your bash is reading keys from the input stdin, you may add a terminal character “arrow” to the datas read on stdin.

ANSI terminal emulation uses escaped sequences, you will find them on http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php

Comment: So, according to the table: `UP ARROW (num keypad)  0;72  56  (0;141)`, what am I supposed to pass as a String?